# How to navigate To a ViewController From xib file of a UIView Class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib

I have a view in my xib file which contain buttons. i want to move to a ViewController when i will press the button `(@IBAction)`. I have used below code

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("About") as! AboutViewController
self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I am getting the error "Value of type 'SlideMenuView' has no member 'presentViewController'.

because my class is a UIView type :

```
class SlideMenuView: UIView { 
}
```

so how can I navigate to other view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it in a different way. In class file

```
class SlideMenuView: UIView { 

 var navigationController: UINavigationController? // Declare a navigation controller variable

// And create a method which take a navigation controller 


  func prepareScreen(navController: UINavigationController)-> UIView {

        navigationController = navController      
        let nibView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SlideMenuView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView        
        self.addSubview(nibView)       
        return nibView
    }

// In Button action 

 @IBAction func btnAction(sender: UIButton) {

         var storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NextViewController") as! UIViewController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

```
// For calling from UIViewController

    slideBarMenuIstance.prepareScreen(self.navigationController!)
```

Answer (score 3):

That is beacuase the class you are trying to present from is a `UIView` and not a `UIViewController`. It has no Present method.

I'm guessing your view (SlideMenuView) is embedded inside a viewcontroller. what you need to do is implement a delegate, and inform your containing viewController to present next Viewcontroller.

code below:

```
@protocol SlideMenuViewDelegate: class {
  func slideMenuViewAboutButtonClicked(menuView: SlideMenuView)
class SlideMenuView: UIView { 

weak var delegate: SlideMenuViewDelegate?

@IBAction func aboutButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
self.delegate?.slideMenuViewAboutButtonClicked(self)
}
```

now, in your viewController, implement this delegate method:

```
func slideMenuViewAboutButtonClicked(menuView: SlideMenuView) {
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("About") as! AboutViewController
self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Also, dont forget to assign the sliderMenuView object the viewcontroller as a delegate.
something like:

```
self.sliderMenuView.delegate = self // (self == the containing viewController
```

Comment: Thanks for help! @Lirik

Comment: @S.Bharti, glad to help. I'll be happy if you could click on the check mark, if this answer was accepted by you.